# Cypress test fails for hexadecimal color in Angular

Tags: angular, cypress

I have a hexadecimal background color. But when I test in cypress it gives me an error. And in the error it shows some other color. But I am providing correct color.
My code is given below:

```
it('color', () => {
  cy.get(':nth-child(5) > .example-button-row > :nth-child(1)')
    .should('exist')
    .should('have.css', 'background-color')
    .and('eq', '#0da2ff');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**eq** works with **rgb** equivalent of **hexdecimal color**. There are two ways of solving it.

**1. Use rgb color with eq.**

**2. Use be.colored instead of eq**

Both examples are given below:

By using **rgb** with **eq** :

```
it('color', () => {
  cy.get(':nth-child(5) > .example-button-row > :nth-child(1)')
    .should('exist')
    .should('have.css', 'background-color')
    .and('eq', 'rgb(13, 162, 255)');
});
```

By using **be.colored** :

```
it('color', () => {
  cy.get(':nth-child(5) > .example-button-row > :nth-child(1)')
    .should('exist')
    .should('have.css', 'background-color')
    .and('be.colored', '#0da2ff');
});
```

Comment: CypressError
The chainer colored was not found. Could not build assertion. Didn't you got this?